# removing or replacing comma from string imported from CSV Data where object is between bracket or any other Regex Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have searched in many places could not find a solution.
I am importing Data from CSV file and then want to create array from this
there for I want to replace comma delimiter with any other  delimiter so when I split string object with comma  should be as it is

I have a string:

```js
VAR newString=Date,Narration,Debit_Account1,  Debit_Amount1  ,Debit_Account2,  Debit_Amount2  ,Debit_Account3, Debit_Amount3 ,Debit_Account4,  Debit_Amount4  ,Credit_Account,  Credit_Amount  
01-04-21,payment to party1,PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),HDFC BANK,( 50,000.00 )
01-04-21,payment to party1,PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),HDFC BANK,( 50,000.00 )
```

I want to remove only those commas which are not between brackets `()`.

I have tried to do this with replace method but could not understand how to give condition for escaping value inside brackets.

Comment: the string is not clear. is it `var newString = "Date,Narration,Debit_Account1,......"` like this or how? I suspect, you are getting this string from CSV reader or something. Is It?

Comment: First guess of me.. just filter the column ```Amount```, replace all ```,``` to ```.``` and after that merge them back together.

Comment: Another idea could be  an imperative process. You could create a new empty string and iterate over every character in the other string, adding it verbarin or replacing it as needed, while keeping a parens counter that you increase when encountering `(` and decrease when encountering `)`. Then you replace only while the counter is zero. - **EDIT:** OK it seems it's unclear what you want, the title says to remove commas between parens but the text says to remove commas **not** between parens... In my example it would mean whether counter is zero or nonzero.

Comment: @CherryDT oh yeah, looks that was the wrong way around. But OP should still clarify what the actual result is supposed to look like. Not sure how much sense `01-04-21,ayment to party1PARTY1( 50,000.00 )PARTY1( 50,000.00 )...`would make.

Comment: @CBroe actually I just realized it's not clear, the title says otherwise. In this case I think you are right and this is what they need...

Comment: I'm guessing this is a CSV file, and OP is trying to grab the data but `split(',')` didn't work for obvious reasons.

Comment: yes I am getting this Data From CSV file filter amount will not work as if any other object have comma then it will make problem in split(',')

Comment: dear @CherryDT actually I want to replace those commas with other delimiter but object inside these brackets should be as it is

Comment: Show the code you have tried and the specific desired result and where you have a challenge with it and we can attempt to help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found My answer thank you for sawing interest in my question answer is

```js
var newstring =Date,Narration,Debit_Account1,  Debit_Amount1  ,Debit_Account2,  Debit_Amount2  ,Debit_Account3, Debit_Amount3 ,Debit_Account4,  Debit_Amount4  ,Credit_Account,  Credit_Amount  
01-04-21,payment to party1,PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),HDFC BANK,( 50,000.00 )
01-04-21,payment to party1,PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),PARTY1,( 50,000.00 ),HDFC BANK,( 50,000.00 )

var answerstring=newstring.replace(/\([^)]*\)/g,(match,startIndex,wholeString)=>{
return match.replace(/,/g,"<>")
})
var newString2=answerstring.replace(/,/g,"_").replace(/<>/g,",");

/*this will give answer as below 
Date_Narration_Debit_Account1_  Debit_Amount1  _Debit_Account2_  Debit_Amount2  _Debit_Account3_ Debit_Amount3 _Debit_Account4_  Debit_Amount4  _Credit_Account_  Credit_Amount  
01-04-21_payment to party1_PARTY1_( 50,000.00 )_PARTY1_( 50,000.00 )_PARTY1_( 50,000.00 )_PARTY1_( 50,000.00 )_HDFC BANK_( 50,000.00 )
01-04-21_payment to party1_PARTY1_( 50,000.00 )_PARTY1_( 50,000.00 )_PARTY1_( 50,000.00 )_PARTY1_( 50,000.00 )_HDFC BANK_( 50,000.00 )

*/
```

I did not understand formula correctly but it did the job if any one can elaborate  this formula please post so other can understand formula

Comment: Note it has to be `replace(/,/g, "?")` and not `replace(/,/, "?")` (note the extra `g`), otherwise it will fail if there are two commas (e.g. `1,000,000.00`)! Also this works only if the contents of the parens never contain a question mark, but I guess with amounts that's safe to assume.

Comment: Dear @CherryDT thanks for correction I have replaced ? with <> as this is not going to come in my data thanks for your comment

Comment: I took the liberty to fix your code accordingly.